# Accepted convention for variable names clashing with keywords / standard libs

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I have a function where I take a `datetime.date` and `time` object as arguments. Let's also say I also want an argument which needs to be named `break` or something very similar. I obviously can't use `break` as an arg without throwing a `SyntaxError`.

What is the most accepted renaming convention to avoid clashing with standard Python library names or keywords?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> - `single_trailing_underscore_`: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword, e.g.
>
>   ```
>   Tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')
>   ```

Specifically, for arguments:

> If a function argument's name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is
>   generally better to append a single trailing underscore rather than
>   use an abbreviation or spelling corruption. Thus `class_` is better
>   than `clss`. (Perhaps better is to avoid such clashes by using a
>   synonym.)

and attribute names:

> - If your public attribute name collides with a reserved keyword, append a single trailing underscore to your attribute name. This is
>     preferable to an abbreviation or corrupted spelling. (However,
>     notwithstanding this rule, `cls` is the preferred spelling for any
>     variable or argument which is known to be a class, especially the
>     first argument to a class method.)